# On Kotlin receiver object and extensions

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to get familiar with the more advanced kotlin features, but i don't know why my little code example compiles and prints "Test A" while not printing "Test B".
Can anybody tell me why Test B is not printed?

```
class One{
    fun delegate(operation: One.()-> Unit){
        operation()
    }
    fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val one= One()
    fun One.doIt(){
        println("Test A")
    }
    one.delegate { doIt() } //prints Test A
    one.delegate {
        fun One.doItDifferently(){
            println("Test B")      //not printed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you don't call the function `.toItDifferently()`, you only define it (it is a [local function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions), i.e. a function defined inside another function). Modify your example to call the function:

```
one.delegate {
    fun One.doItDifferently(){
        println("Test B")
    }
    doItDifferently() // <- here
}
```

(UPD, based on the comment) You can call `delegate` with an [anonymous function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions) like this:

```
one.delegate( // note the parenthesis, not the curly braces
    fun One.(){
        println("Test B")
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I thought I'm calling delegate and passing the function to it and it should be called by operation(). Is that wrong?

Comment: You're not passing any function. That lambda block is of type `One.() -> Unit` and cannot return anything. You are also not using its return value (which is of type `Unit`). All that is happening is that the function is declared and never used.

Comment: @MikeBalthasar added an example in my answer, it's not supported however to use reflection to call local functions. As hotkey has demonstrated, a lambda isn't the same as an argument list.

Comment: @MikeBalthasar, updated the answer with how you could call `delegate` with an anonymous `fun`.

Comment: @hotkey: thanks for the update, that made it very clear!

Answer (score 1):

You're not *calling* the function.

That is a local extension function on the class `One` and you are just declaring it. It now exists and is usable in the current scope, but does nothing by itself.

You would need to call/invoke it for it to do anything, as with any normal method:

```
one.delegate {
    fun One.doItDifferently(){
        println("Test B")
    }

    doItDifferently()
}
```

IntelliJ will actually give you a warning that this function is never used.

Edit: as per your comment, you aren't *passing* the function at all. This is not possible yet if you want to *return* the function as reflection does not support local functions.

If you try this:

```
class One {
    fun delegate(operation: One.() -> KFunction<*>) {
        operation().call(this)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array) {
    val one = One()
    fun One.doIt() {
        println("Test A")
    }
    one.delegate {
        fun One.doItDifferently() {
            println("Test B")      //not printed
        }
        this::doItDifferently
    }
}
```

You'll get:

> Exception in thread "main" kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Introspecting local functions, lambdas and anonymous functions is not yet fully supported in Kotlin reflection

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
one.delegate {
    fun One.doItDifferently(){
        println("Test B")      //not printed
    }
}
```

will just create an empty function with a nested function. `doItDifferently()` is just declared, but never invoked. Hence, `println("Test B")` will never be executed.